# Why do I have multiple tmux processes?

Tags: tmux

I use `tmux attach` to start tmux and have the following lines in my tmux.conf:

```
new  -n TeX   bash
neww -n Shell bash
```

After starting the terminal emulator and running pgrep I get the following:

```
 ~  $ pgrep -lL tmux
41479 /Users/nmk/.homebrew/bin/tmux attach
41481 /Users/nmk/.homebrew/bin/tmux attach
```

The tmux session I see is 0. What is the second process doing? Are those two the client and the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one is the server. If you do `ps x` you'll see that one is attached to a pty and one isn't. If you run another separate `tmux` session, you'll see three processes - two with ptys and one, the server, without.